# What is the <link> tag's default MIME type?

Tags: html, apache, http, mime-types

When you set a `link` tag like the following:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style/global.css">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">
```

Does it get a default MIME type due to its `rel` attribute without any custom `httpd.conf` settings (i.e., the `stylesheet` link relationship hints it's a `text/css` file)?

If yes, what are the "default" MIME types for `stylesheet`, `alternate` and `shortcut icon`?

Comment: Did you Google your question yet? I mostly look at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link) for things like this.

Comment: I did Google it - I don't know if my question wasn't specific enough, but I didn't find any info on whether the browser reads these mentioned tags as text/css and application/octet-stream or as whatever Apache sends it as

Comment: Have a look at my answer. BTW: If you want to _force_ a default yourself you could always do that with your .htaccess or httpd file.

Comment: The `script` question is different and not closely related; it should be a separate question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For HTML5:

In general, the [`type` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-html5-20130806/document-metadata.html#attr-link-type) gives the MIME type. But an external resource link type (which can be specified with the `rel` attribute) can define a default MIME type, which gets used if no MIME type is specified explicitly:

> If there is no type metadata, but the external resource link type has a default type defined, then the user agent must assume that the resource is of that type.

This is the case for the [`stylesheet` link type](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-html5-20130806/links.html#link-type-stylesheet), which has the default MIME type `text/css`:

> The default type for resources given by the `stylesheet` keyword is `text/css`.

No default type for the [`icon` link type](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-html5-20130806/links.html#rel-icon) (but `image/` has to be assumed):

> There is no default type for resources given by the `icon` keyword. However, for the purposes of determining the type of the resource, user agents must expect the resource to be an image.

The [`alternate` link type](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-html5-20130806/links.html#rel-alternate) can’t have a default MIME type, because it’s a [hyperlink](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-html5-20130806/links.html#hyperlink) link type, not an [external resource](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-html5-20130806/links.html#external-resource-link) link type.

Comment: +1 for the links, but do Apache headers override this or not?

Comment: @gchiconi: Yes, HTTP headers should always override. The value given in the `type` is "purely advisory", it is "used as a hint": "User agents must not consider the `type` attribute authoritative — upon fetching the resource, user agents must not use the `type` attribute to determine its actual type." So it is only used before the resource is fetched (otherwise you could "dictate" the MIME type of externally hosted files; and MIME types specified on the HTML level will be out of date often; etc.).

Answer (score 1):

The [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link#attr-rel) Docs say:

> **rel**
>   This attribute names a relationship of the linked document to the current document. The attribute must be a space-separated list of the link types values. ***The most common use of this attribute is to specify a link to an external style sheet: the rel attribute is set to stylesheet, and the href attribute is set to the URL of an external style sheet to format the page.*** WebTV also supports the use of the value next for rel to preload the next page in a document series.

This is not telling the default value of the ref attribute. But: `rel` names a relationship of the linked document to the current document, so this attribute must be set to the desired relationship `stylesheet` in order to tell the browser what to interpret from this link.

The new HTML5 Doctype makes the `script` tags `type` attribute superfluous. So only use `<script>...</script>` (for inline scripts) or `<script src="<SOURCE>">...</script>` (for includes) in your html if you're using the HTML5 Doctype, else add the type attribute.

Answer (score 0):

`rel` specifies how the document relates to the webpage and does not affect MIME-Type.

`href` is the source file to be loaded and the MIME-Type is determined based on your web server settings (for instance, my Apache 2 server associates *.php files with the `application/x-httpd-php` type but a non-configured server will see this as whatever its default MIME-Type is (usually `text/plain`).

`type` will override whatever the server returns from it's diagnosis on `href` and is set manually (not a required field).

For `<script>` resources, the same process takes place but modern browsers have deprecated the `type` and `language` fields unless special cases are present (like using VBScript instead of Javascript - whoever the hell does that anymore).

EDIT:

To address your last comment - Apache does not default to an octet stream unless you specify this in apache2.conf (or httpd.conf/other .conf files).  The only reason it would default to this is if you were primarily serving binary files and wanted to avoid browsers parsing the files as plain text in a browser when they are clicked on.

Comment: Is there any reason for serving php as `application/x-httpd-php` instead of `text/html`/`application/javascript`/whatever? After all, client-side will only read the served code, and not php lines

Comment: It's a way for the browser and server to communicate efficiently.  If the server sends over a binary image file using ASCII characters (aka `text/html`), it will be much larger than normal, plus it'll show up as a ton of text characters instead of a pretty picture.  Setting `application/x-httpd-php` will restrict access to the files from outside viewing (so your passwords and such are protected in your MySQL queries, etc) - assuming you set your Apache server to `Allow none, Deny all`

Comment: "rel ... does not affect MIME-Type." This is incorrect. See http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/links.html#link-type-stylesheet "The default type for resources given by the stylesheet keyword is text/css." In all other cases, there is no default mime type.

Comment: "type will override whatever the server returns"/ This is also wrong. the soec says "User agents must not consider the type attribute authoritative — upon fetching the resource, user agents must not use the type attribute to determine its actual type. Only the actual type ... is used to determine whether to apply the resource, not the aforementioned assumed type."

Comment: I'm still waiting for some agreement on whether `rel` does or does not affect the MIME type, thus unaccepted.

Comment: `rel` is not meant to be used to determine MIME-Types.  A setting of `rel="stylesheet"` will in fact default to `text/css` from browser logic but this is merely from the absence of a `type`.  And to make this more understandable (because I know I'm terrible at that) - you can set `rel="icon"` and, from the same link @Alohci supplied, "There is no default type for resources given by the icon keyword."  So while I should have worded a little differently, the answer is essentially the same.  While using `rel` with a stylesheet exclusively will default to `text/css`, that is not its only option.

Comment: Here's another reference that may be useful http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/link

Answer (score 0):

Take this example provided by Windows:

```
    <LINK REL = "stylesheet"
TYPE = "<code><b class="cfe">mime/type</b></mark>"
HREF = "<code><b class="cfe">url</b></mark>">
```

where the value REL= "stylesheet" indicates that the target source is a style sheet, mime/type is the MIME type for the style sheet, and url is the address of the style sheet file.

Each stylesheet has it's own MIME type and Cascading style sheets (CSS) have the default MIME type **text/css**.

When adding a favicon to your website, you add something like this within your web page

`<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/vnd.Microsoft.icon" href="/some-folder/some-image.ico">`

The "href" is simply the *location* on your web server where you stored the icon. For example, you would type "*/images/favicon-logo.ico*" if your favicon is stored in the images folder and is named "*favicon-logo.ico.*"

There also some "Unofficial MIME Types":
Although the unofficial MIME types will work with most web browsers, they do not work with Internet Explorer. Therefore, avoid using the following MIME Types if you want all of your visitors to view the favicon: "image/png," "image/gif," image/jpeg," or any other variation.